# How do I check if a certain value exists?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a historization table called CUR_VALID. This table looks something like this:

```
ID  CUR_VALID
1   N
1   N
1   Y
2   N
2   Y
3   Y
```

For every ID there needs to be one Y. If there is no Y or multiple Y there is something wrong. The statment for checking if there are multiple Y I already got. Now I only need to check for every ID if there is one Y existing. Im just not sure how to do that. This is what I have so far. So how do I check if the Value 'Y' exists?

```
SELECT Count(1) [Number of N]
      ,MAX(CUR_VALID = 'N')
      ,[BILL_ID]
      ,[BILL_MONTH]
      ,[BILL_SRC_ID]
 FROM db.dbo.table
  GROUP BY [BILL_ID]
      ,[BILL_MONTH]
      ,[BILL_SRC_ID]
 Having MAX(CUR_VALID = 'N') > 1
```

Comment: Yor Syntax Looks like SQL-Server not like mysql. Maybe you should Change the tags

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why are you fiddling with 'N' when you are interested in 'Y'?

Use conditional aggregation to get the count of the value your are interested in.

```
SELECT 
  COUNT(*) AS number_of_all,
  COUNT(CASE WHEN cur_valid = 'Y' THEN 1 END) AS number_of_y,
  COUNT(CASE WHEN cur_valid = 'N' THEN 1 END) AS number_of_n,
  bill_id,
  bill_month,
  bill_src_id,
FROM db.dbo.table
GROUP BY bill_id, bill_month, bill_src_id;
```

Add a `HAVING` clause in order to get only valid

```
HAVING COUNT(CASE WHEN cur_valid = 'Y' THEN 1 END) = 1
```

or invalid

```
HAVING COUNT(CASE WHEN cur_valid = 'Y' THEN 1 END) <> 1
```

bills.

Comment: Good answer. Works perfectly. The idea behind the 'N' was to only COUNT 1 Record. If this Record was N I would know that there is a mistake cause there needs to be an Y. Anyways your answer is just perfect :)

Answer (score 1):

This query returns both not having at least one 'Y' value and more than one 'Y' value ID's.

First, sum up the Y values and relate to each id, then select not 1 ones from that table.

```
select * from (
    select ID, SUM(case when CUR_VALID = 'Y' then 1 else 0 end) as CNT 
    from table
    group by ID
) b where b.CNT <> 1
```

[DBFiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/p2cBdn36FakV199cPF1w7g/0)

Answer (score 1):

The following query will give you the list of id for which your integrity condition is not met: *For every ID there needs to be one Y. If there is no Y or multiple Y there is something wrong.*

```
select T1.id from table T1 where (select count(*) from table T2 where T2.id=T1.id and T2.CUR_VALID='Y')!=1
```

Answer (score 1):

As I understand, you want to get all the `id` for which your integrity check passes. And integrity check for you means, there is only one row with `CUR_VALID` value equal to `Y` in the `CUR_VALID` table.

This can be achieved by a `group by` clause:

```
select id from CUR_VALID 
where CUR_VALID.CUR_VALID = 'Y'
group by id
having count(CUR_VALID.CUR_VALID) = 1;
```

Comment: I'd make this `count(*)` as you want to count rows. `count(expression)` only counts non-null occurrences, but `CUR_VALID.CUR_VALID` can never be null, because of your `WHERE` clause. So using `count(CUR_VALID.CUR_VALID)` is making this query look more complicated than it actually is and lessens readability.

Comment: True! it's better to write `count(*)` in having clause